# Why is Spring causing permission issues with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

This is my first question on Stackoverflow thank you for reading it. Basically every time I start up my program which has Spring installed as a gem, no matter what command I run I get this error: Errno::EACCES Permission Denied. I have tried running commands with sudo and the same error appears. The only workaround I have found so far is to comment out Spring in the gem file and run bundle install again. Does anyone have any insight on why this might be happening and how to have spring running without this error appearing.

Comment: Could you post the text of the error? Sounds like Spring is pointing at a directory that it doesn’t have wrote permission for (which can happen).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 4: from -e:1:in `<main>'
 3: from /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
 2: from /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
 1: from /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:2:in `setsid': Operation not permitted (Errno::EPERM)

Comment: Odd, you wrote in the base note that the error was `EACCES` but in the output it is `EPERM`. That makes sense, since the line indicated is a call to `Process.setsid`, which according to the docs only errors with `EPERM`. I'm a bit hazy on circumstances where that happens, but could it be you've already got spring running? Maybe do `spring stop` at the command line and then try again?

Comment: Great that fixed it thank you so much